# How to change the era period?

Tags: substrate-node-template, era

I believe the default `era` period in `substrate-node-template` is 24 hours. Is there a way for me to change that period?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eras are measured in sessions. The duration of sessions are dependent on the consensus mechanism.

To reduce the number of sessions per era, simply adjust the [`SessionsPerEra`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/77c15d2546276a865b6e8f1c5d4b1d0ec1961e72/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L128) value in the implementation of `pallet_staking::Config`.

In BABE, the [`EpochDuration`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/77c15d2546276a865b6e8f1c5d4b1d0ec1961e72/frame/babe/src/lib.rs#L127) config member is used to set the number of slots (and therefore the amount of time) in a session. This can only be set in the genesis. The actual parameters given to BABE which determine the block time are in the [`epoch_config`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/77c15d2546276a865b6e8f1c5d4b1d0ec1961e72/frame/babe/src/lib.rs#L316) field of `pallet_babe`'s `GenesisConfig`.

To sum up: you have a few variables to play with - the time between blocks, the amount of blocks in a session, and the amount of sessions in an era. By adjusting these, you can adjust the overall time in a staking era.

Comment: Very insightful. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to change it by a runtime upgrade?

Comment: It's possible to change the sessions per era in a runtime upgrade, but not possible (with BABE) to update the block time or number of slots in a session with a runtime upgrade.